# Realtime database dont change

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
mAuth
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Demail, Dpasvord)
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
    @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        User user = new User(Dname, Demail, Dpasvord);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(
          FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
        ).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
          @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Uspjesno ste se registrovali!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I have problem with this code, authentication works fine, but changing in realtime database don't work, app is connected, rules set to allow.

Comment: Thank you for answer, this is my first post, next time i will formate it. I am stuck on that line, because my app just show progressbar and never hide because there is an stuck... i write to hide if isSuccess...

Comment: "don't work" is hard to help with. Set breakpoints on every line in your code, and run the app in a debugger. Does it reach the breakpoints? What is the value of all variables on each line? Do they all look like what you'd expect them to be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem fix that i open new project and coppy all files there and now working fine, i think 90% problem is dependencies of firebase that i add in my project, i add some what i need and some what i dont need. OR 10% can be that because i import more class than i need..